# Python: Console with infinite loop, getting out of stack space

Tags: python, multithreading, console

The implementation is pasted below. However, each time I actually input something in the console, I get this error:

```
        while executing
    "::tcl::Bgerror {out of stack space (infinite loop?)} {-code 1 -level 0 -errorcode NONE -errorinfo {out of stack space (infinite loop?)
        while execu..."
    error in background error handler:

out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

This is used by another application(Matplotlib GUI), that instantiates ConsoleInput, and then uses the most recent user entry for itself.

Why is this error happening, and how can I fix ConsoleInput?
Is there a way to check if there is pending input, and only read then, rather than loop constantly?

```
import threading


class ConsoleInput(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.exit = False
        self.most_recent_entry = None

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit:
            self.most_recent_entry = raw_input()
```

Here is the relevant part of the GUI that's using the console input:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.console_input = ConsoleInput()
    self.console_input.start()
    self.run()

def run(self):
    self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
    self.figure.canvas.set_window_title(self.title)
    self.gen_data()
    plt.connect('button_press_event', self.on_fig_update_event)
    plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_fig_update_event)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

def gen_data(self):
    if self.console_input.most_recent_entry:
        print self.console_input.most_recent_entry:
```

Comment: Is there an infinite loop that's editing a GUI element somewhere? Maybe in the code that's actually *using* the `ConsoleInput` instance?

Comment: Yes, there is. The input from the console is then used to update a gui appropriately. But I did not get this error before including the console input element.

Comment: Can you share the code that's using `ConsoleInput`? I think that's probably the piece that needs to change.

Comment: I did. The interesting thing is that the error happens only after I enter something in console.

Comment: this seems like bad design ... I suspect you can find a key_press_event for matplotlib ...

Comment: It's not bad if it is easily fixable. I can check the event, and only trigger ConsoleInput if key pressed?

Comment: Do you have concrete idea how will I fix it? How would the new ConsoleInput look like, if it only reads when it is triggered by the GUI, which listens to, say, KeyReleased event?

Comment: Why aren't you using a GUI control to get input? It's highly unusual to have a GUI program read from stdin.

Comment: Because matplotlib cannot read a number from a text box. If you think otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: matplotlib can definately read from a textbox ... why wouldnt it be able to?

Comment: Here I was advised it was impossible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449398/matplotlib-user-enters-numeric-input-through-figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit] Based on new information you have provided ... try this solution
(original solutions found below)

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #this stuff is bad dont do it
        #self.console_input = ConsoleInput()
        #self.console_input.start()
        self.run()
    def on_console(self,evt):

        print "data = ",self.var.get()

    def run(self):
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
        self.figure.canvas.set_window_title("a title")
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25) # Make space for stuff
        plt.plot([1,2,3],[5,5,6])
        #add stuff to our frame
        self.var = StringVar() #hold user variable
        b = Button(self.figure.canvas.get_tk_widget(),text="Update Chart!")
        b.pack(side="bottom",fill="both",padx=4,pady=1)
        slider = Entry(self.figure.canvas.get_tk_widget(),textvariable = self.var)
        slider.pack(side="bottom", fill='both',  padx=4, pady=4)
        b.bind("<Button-1>",self.on_console)
        plt.show()
```

two things something like this maybe what you are looking for ... but in general you really shouldnt be reading stdin with gui programs ...

A much better solution is to get the info from the gui something like

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tkSimpleDialog
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #this stuff is bad dont do it
        #self.console_input = ConsoleInput()
        #self.console_input.start()
        self.run()
    def on_console(self,evt):
        data = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("HELLO?","You?")
        print data
        #do something with the data (and self.figure perhaps)
    def run(self):
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
        self.figure.canvas.set_window_title("a title")
        plt.connect('key_release_event', self.on_console)
        plt.show()
```

however if you really want to use console input you should probably use the cmd module

```
import cmd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
class SomeClass:
        def __init__(self):
            #this stuff is bad dont do it
            #self.console_input = ConsoleInput()
            #self.console_input.start()
            self.run()
        def on_console(self,evt):
            print "EVT:",evt
            MyCmdInterface(self).cmdloop()
        def run(self):
            self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
            self.figure.canvas.set_window_title("a title")
            plt.connect('key_release_event', self.on_console)
            plt.show()

class MyCmdInterface(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple command processor example."""
    prompt="CMD:"
    def __init__(self,guiInst):
        print "MPL Interactive Command Interface! type HELP for help."
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.gui = guiInst
    def do_HELP(self,line):
        print "Some Help Message"
    def do_SET(self, line):
        assert "=" in line,"SET COMMANDS REQUIRE <varName>=<valName>"
        var,val = line.split("=",1)
        #do something
    def do_NEWDATA(self,line):
        newdata = map(float,line.split(","))
        print "SET latest_values = %s"%newdata
        self.gui.latest_values = newdata
        #do something with new data

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True
    #aliases for exit
    do_EXIT = do_exit = do_QUIT = do_quit = do_DONE = do_done = do_EOF

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = SomeClass()
    s.run()
```

this also demonstrates what a short runnable code example looks like

Comment: Here I was told it was impossible:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449398/matplotlib-user-enters-numeric-input-through-figure

Comment: Also, your solution does not work. It freezes the app, and does not really read anything. Not sure if I should accept it, because otherwise in the future people won't answer my questions.

Comment: its a modal dialog it sits on top of the app and blocks input until it is closed ... if you want it non-modal you will need to create your own simple tkinter frame asking for input (assuming default tkinter backend ... ) I think you need to better define your problem if you want a better answer

Comment: Can you please look at this while you're at it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454853/matplotlib-runtimeerror-locator-attempting-to-generate-2000-ticks

I think it has to do with the fact that at start, when it has only a handful of data points, it can happen that all y-values are same, but why is that a problem?

Comment: no idea and you do not provide enough information to get an answer ... but see edit on this solution